# In Qt socket write data is not reaching the server

Tags: android, c++, qt, sockets

Writing a simple application to communicate with Android device from PC Qt application.

on initial startup of my app, succesfully able to connect to the android app.

My Signals:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(connected()));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readyRead()));

void MyApp::connected()
{
    qDebug() << "connected...";
    socket->write("Init Connection \n");
    socket->flush();
}

void MyApp::readyRead()
{
    QString readData;
    qDebug() << "reading...";

    while(socket->bytesAvailable())
        readData= socket->readAll();

    qDebug()<<"Read Finished";

    if(socket->isWritable())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Yes Writable";
        socket->write("New Data");
        socket->flush();

    }
    else
        qDebug()<<"No Writable"; 
}
```

In `connected` method `socket->write` is successful and Android app able to read the data but in  `readyRead`, `socket->write` is returning the number of bytes written but not reaching to the android app.

Note: On application close or socket close, data is read at the server end which is running in Android app.

Tell me if any more data is required.

EDIT:

1.Android app running on a tablet and qt pc app. Both are running on same network (intranet).

2.Created `Qtcpscoket` in a single program.

3.Created `ServerSocket` on android app and on  `socket>connectToHost(server_ip,portNo,QIODevice::ReadWrite);` at Qt app
`onConnected` method  is called.subsequently `socket->write("Init Connection \n");` is read at android app.

Comment: Please show more, like how do you create sockets? What kind of sockets is it? If TCP sockets, how do you accept new connections? How do you receive the data? How do you know the `write` was successful? Maybe the error isn't in the PC C++ program but in the Android program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't think there is some problem in the Android end because the same app receives data from a android client socket.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments, so I'll write here. You can use `QIODevice` function `bool QIODevice::waitForBytesWritten(int msecs) [virtual]` instead of `bool flush()`. If your PC application stops then the problem is in writing your data in second time. Or you can check value returned by function `flush()`.